# Prove that $p \ge 5$ is prime, then the remainder of $p$ upon division by $6$ is $1$ or $5$.

Tags: prime-numbers

An example in my textbook, but I'm not quite sure how to set this one up, because of the $p \ge 5$ part. How do I start it off?

Comment: Suppose that, for example, $p$ gives the remainder 2. What does it say you about number p?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $p\ge 5$, then $p$ is odd. So, the remainder has to be odd. But, the remainder cannot be $3$ because $p\ge 5$ cannot be the form $6m+3$ which is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Okay, and then how would I show that the remainder has to be odd? I can do examples and see that it is true, but how would I generally prove it?

Comment: @J-Play: If the remainder is even $2m$, $p$ can be represented as $p=6k+2m$. This is even, which is a contradiction (a prime number $p\ge 5$ is odd).