# Prove that if $p\ge 5$ is prime, then $p^2 + 1$ is composite

Tags: proof-writing

So, coming off of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967114/prove-that-p-ge-5-is-prime-then-the-remainder-of-p-upon-division-by-6-is), I know how to find out what the remainder is, so after figuring whether the remainder is $1$ or $5$, would I just plug in $p = 6q + (1\ \text{or}\ 5)$ into $p^2+1$?

As in, making it $(6q+1)^2+1$ or $(6q+5)^2+1$?

Comment: Try expanding the expressions $(6q + 1)^2 + 1$ and $(6q + 5)^2 + 1$, then factor once you have simplified each expression.  Are the expressions you obtain divisible by a number larger than $1$?

Comment: hint: simply prove that if $p \geq 3$ is prime, then $p^2+1$ is composite and this result follows. xp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: Think about even and odd.